# Node Voltage Analysis with independent and dependent voltage sources

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ARJR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm having trouble solving for the voltage drop across the 80 ohm resistor using the node voltage analysis method. I can get the correct value (120 volts) doing a mesh current analysis on the three loops but can't seem to come up with this same value doing a node voltage analysis. I created a supernode at the V1 node and V3 (drop across the R4 resistor) but not sure if I got the current polarities correct.

Comment: should be correct now

Comment: A couple of things: First, the question should be *text* in the post itself, otherwise it cannot be indexed, searched, or read by anyone that isn't loading images. Second, you need to elaborate on what you've tried, and why you're stumped. You can't just post a question verbatim from a textbook and hope to get an answer here.

Comment: I'm not sure where to write the specific question I have that applies to this schematic.

Comment: I still need help on where I go in order to type in my specific question for this post. Note, the one answer submitted below is correct and actually answered my original question

Comment: I think it's correct now. As I mentioned in my last comment one person responded and answered my question. I had the sign wrong on one of the currents at the supernode.

Comment: I've voted to re-open your question, as you've added the text and explained what you've tried. It's now in good format.